# Zeroing the Long Range Scope with multiple zoom levels

Tags: dayz-standalone

I'm using the [Long Range Scope](http://dayz-standalone.wikia.com/wiki/Long_range_scope) with the [Mosin](http://dayz-standalone.wikia.com/wiki/Mosin_9130). The scope has multiple zoom levels: the default zoom which is activated by clicking the right mouse button, and additional zoom levels activated by pressing the <kbd>+</kbd> key on the num pad.

I know that I can use <kbd>PgUp</kbd> and <kbd>PgDn</kbd> to zero the scope to different distances.

So, my question is this. If I zero the scope to 300m, does that mean it's zeroed to 300m only for the default (right mouse button click) zoom level? Or, does that zeroing also apply to all levels of additional zooming?

If it does not apply to the additional zoom levels, then how do I compensate while zoomed in further?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It compensates for all zoom levels, aside from firing from the hip of course.